# MPI How to make variables initialized in root process visible in other processes

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I've got couple of test methods that initialize array a0 but the array differs in size with each method. These arrays are initialized in process rank==0. Now in other file I have an implementation for a method that makes some computations using values from that table (it doesn't modify them). 
It looks somewhat like this (pseudo code):

```
res=0;
x=0;
for(i=mystart;i<myend;++i)
  for(j=0;j<length;++j)
    x+= a[j] * multiplier;

MPI_Reduce(&x,&res,1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I have a requirement that those computations can only be processed by processes other than root, but since they don't see what values does a[] hold, it doesn't work. I tried MPI_Bcast(a, ?, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD), but I can't get value of the size, since it differes with every method call. The whole code is kinda big but if someone wants to take a look I can publish it somewhere...

Is there an easy way to make those fields visible to the other processes?

EDIT:
As suggested I uploaded the code:
main func: http://pastebin.com/tREeHMZM
methods for comutation and class declaration: http://pastebin.com/BBedJ7bA

Dividing the loops works fine it's just those comptations that don't work, and I'm not sure how to make those processes communicate with each other.

Comment: You probably do need to post some more of the relevant fragments. This helps keeps the question concise and makes it more of an MCVE. I'd post the `MPI_Bcast` and the "client side" code that receives them. And enough code regarding the generation and usage of the size. To prevent "going round-n-round" on posting more here [based on feedback], add a link to [e.g. pastebin] for full code. When you get enough feedback to solve the problem, you can edit the fragments to create a whole question here [and optionally remove the external link]. You can post all here. Limit is 30,000 chars

Comment: As I couldnt paste another link, here's my attempt at making Calc method parallel: http://pastebin.com/t53fH3fh

Comment: @Craig Estey I've uploaded the code as you suggested

Comment: I downloaded all the code, but, AFAICT, `Function.h` is missing. I'll try to analyze things without it, but having it would help.

Comment: Broadcast the size first, then broadcast the array.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll If i first bcast size `MPI_Bcast(&size, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` and then try to bcast the array `MPI_Bcast(x0, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` I get segmentation fault every time. The root process sees that array and I can print it, but I can't access it from any other process. Any clue what might be wrong?

Comment: @adammayer I assume your array `x0` is of type `MPI_DOUBLE`, not `MPI_INT`. Can you confirm that your `size` is correct on other processes before the 2nd broadcast? Have you pre-allocated the memory you need on the other processes before the 2nd broadcast?

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Yes, the x0 is of type double, I forgot to modify the parameter after pasting it. The size if correct, after the first broadcast I printed the values I was able to bcast on the other processes, and each of them has values `length`,`size`,`mult` and `error`, though all the processes except the root process, don't see value `length_2` and when I try to broadcast any array I get segmentation fault. Even if I specify the size argument of broadcast in the first test (I know the size=8) I still get segmentation fault. So it didn't work even if I bcasted the size parameter first.

Answer (score 0):

Why not broadcast the size of the array you're going to broadcast first?

Answer (score 0):

You were really quite close. I believe I was able to correct the program and the corrected text is below.

*Note: I started writing this explanation before I actually modified the program, so replace "you must do" with "I did"*

I was able to download and build your program. I was able to work around the missing `Function.h`, based on what I already had by changing `Function::value` into just `Function_value` [a global function].

The one thing you *do* have to do is have rank 0 get the random seed value. It has to bcast this *first*, so the client ranks can get it so their calls to `shuffle` will produce the same results. So, I created a global `ranseed`, set from a bcast in `main`, that `shuffle` can see it.

I changed the `test*` routines to *always* compute `x0`, `y0`, `a`, and `c`, regardless of rank. Otherwise, the compiler was complaining about possibly uninitialized values for those pointers. The computation is small. No need to broadcast these values. If this precalculation were intensive [which it isn't], then bcast-ing the arrays would be the way to go.

I think you already realized this in the MPI version of `calcError` because you were commenting out the bcasts for these arrays.

AFAICT, your MPI `calcError` looks good *except* for two things:

(1) The `MPI_Reduce` call should *not* be inside the `if (myid_c >= 0)` block. I think it needs to be at the bottom after this block (i.e. even rank 0 needs to call it).

(2) In the *old* place for the `MPI_Reduce` [inside the `if`], I think you need an `error_p = error;` after the double level for loops because `error_p` is the value that the clients *send* [and `error` is what the root *receives*]

I added a `-R` command line option to allow manual setting the of the random seed value. I also added a `-M` option to switch between the MPI and non-MPI versions of `calcError`

I've run the program using the mpi mode: `mpirun -np 8 <program> -M` and all tests seemed to work. I did `ctrl-c` on `testL` after a while, so no guarantees on that.

---

Here's a single [archive] file, similar to your paste, the file separater line is `% <filename>`

It has all my outlined corrections [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup].

**Warning:** Be careful when extracting `Function.h` as I had to create a skeleton version, so if your version has a class definition, it will get lost.

```
% Error.h
// mpisize/Error.h -- Error class

#ifndef _mpisize_Error_h_
#define _mpisize_Error_h_

class Error {
  private:
    double *v;
    double *x0;
    double *y0;
    double *a;
    double *c;
    int length;                         // grid length
    double length_2;
    double mult;
    int size;                           // number of gausses to add
    double error;

  public:
    void setValues(double *v, int length, double mult);
    void setCoefficients(double *x0,double *y0, double *a,double *c, int size);
    void calcError(int mpiflg);
    void calcErrorStd();
    void calcErrorMpi();
    double getError();
};

#endif
% Function.h
// mpisize/Function.h -- Function class

#ifndef _mpisize_Function_h_
#define _mpisize_Function_h_

#include <math.h>

//Function code
double
Function_value(double x, double y, double x0, double y0, double a, double c);

#endif
% mpisize.h
// mpisize/mpisize.h -- Function class

#ifndef _mpisize_mpisize_h_
#define _mpisize_mpisize_h_

#include <math.h>
#include "Error.h"
#include "Function.h"

#ifdef _MPISIZE_GLO_
#define EXTRN_MPISIZE       /**/
#else
#define EXTRN_MPISIZE       extern
#endif

EXTRN_MPISIZE int opt_debug;
EXTRN_MPISIZE int opt_send;
EXTRN_MPISIZE int glob_rank;
EXTRN_MPISIZE double tvzero;

double
tvgetf(void);

int
dbgif(int lvl);

void
_dbgprt(const char *fmt,...);

#define dbgprt(_lvl,_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (dbgif(_lvl)) \
            _dbgprt(_fmt); \
    } while (0)

#endif
% ErrMpi.cpp
// mpisize/ErrMpi -- MPI threaded version of calcError

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include "mpisize.h"

void
Error::calcErrorMpi()
{
    int mystart, myend;
    int myid, myid_c;
    int numproc, numproc_c;

    //MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
    myid = glob_rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numproc);

    myid_c = myid - 1;
    numproc_c = numproc - 1;

    // NOTE/BUG: length_2 is double, so it needs MPI_DOUBLE
#if 0
    MPI_Bcast(&length, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    // MPI_Bcast(&length_2, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  // broken
    // MPI_Bcast(&length_2, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  // fixed
#endif

    MPI_Bcast(&error, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    // MPI_Bcast(v, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Bcast(&size, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&mult, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // NOTE/BUG: these are arrays, so second argument must be array count
    if (opt_send) {
        MPI_Bcast(x0, size, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(y0, size, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(a, size, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(c, size, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    double error_p = 0;

    error = 0;

    if (myid_c >= 0) {
        mystart = (length / numproc_c) * myid_c;

        if (length % numproc_c > myid_c) {
            mystart += myid_c;
            myend = mystart + (length / numproc_c) + 1;
        }
        else {
            mystart += length % numproc_c;
            myend = mystart + (length / numproc_c);
        }

        dbgprt(2,"calcErrorMpi: STARTUP myid_c=%d numproc_c=%d length=%d length_2=%g mystart=%d myend=%d\n",
            myid_c,numproc_c,length,length_2,mystart,myend);

        double dv;
        double vtmp;

        for (int i = mystart; i < myend; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                vtmp = 0.0;
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                    vtmp += Function_value((i - length_2) * mult,
                        (j - length_2) * mult,
                        x0[k], y0[k], a[k], c[k]);
                dv = v[i * length + j] - vtmp;
                error += dv * dv;
            }
        }

        error_p = error;

        // if(myid == 0 ) cout << "Proces " << myid << " after reducing error = " << error << endl;

    }

    dbgprt(2,"calcErrorMpi: RED/BEF error_p=%g error=%g\n",error_p,error);
    MPI_Reduce(&error_p, &error, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    dbgprt(2,"calcErrorMpi: RED/AFT error_p=%g error=%g\n",error_p,error);
}
% Error.cpp
// mpisize/Error -- Error routines

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "Error.h"
#include "Function.h"

using namespace std;

void
Error::setValues(double *v, int length, double mult)
{
    this->v = v;
    this->length = length;
    this->mult = mult;
    length_2 = length * 0.5;
    cout << "test" << endl;
}

void
Error::setCoefficients(double *x0, double *y0, double *a, double *c, int size)
{
    this->x0 = x0;
    this->y0 = y0;
    this->a = a;
    this->c = c;
    this->size = size;
}

void
Error::calcErrorStd()
{
    double dv;
    double vtmp;

    error = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            vtmp = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                vtmp += Function_value((i - length_2) * mult,
                    (j - length_2) * mult,
                    x0[k], y0[k], a[k], c[k]);
            dv = v[i * length + j] - vtmp;
            error += dv * dv;
        }
    }
}

void
Error::calcError(int mpiflg)
{

    if (mpiflg)
        calcErrorMpi();
    else
        calcErrorStd();
}

double
Error::getError()
{
    return sqrt(error);
}
% Function.cpp
// mpisize/Function -- function code

#include "Function.h"

// Function code
double
Function_value(double x, double y, double x0, double y0, double a, double c )
{
   return a * exp(-((x - x0) * (x - x0) + (y - y0) * (y - y0)) * c);
}
% mpisize.cpp
// mpisize/mpisize -- main program and test routines

#define _MPISIZE_GLO_
#include "mpisize.h"
#include "Error.h"
#include "Function.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const int LEN = 1250;
const int LEN_2 = LEN / 2;
const int SIZE = LEN * LEN;
const int SHUFFLE_TIMES = 2 * SIZE;
const double MULT = 0.1;
const int COMPLEXITY = 8;

int ranseed;
int opt_mpi;

double
generate(double x, double y, double *x0, double *y0, double *a, double *c, int indexS, int indexE)
{
    double v = 0.0;

    for (int i = indexS; i < indexE; i++) {
        v += Function_value(x, y, x0[i], y0[i], a[i], c[i]);
    }
    return v;
}

void
generate(double *v, double *x0, double *y0, double *a, double *c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < LEN; j++)
            v[i * LEN + j] = generate((i - LEN_2) * MULT, (j - LEN_2) * MULT,
                x0, y0, a, c, 0, COMPLEXITY);
}

void
shuffle(double *v)
{
    // losowo przestawiamy polozenia czastek
    int i;
    int j;
    double vtmp;

    srandom(ranseed);

    for (int k = 0; k < SHUFFLE_TIMES; k++) {
        i = random() % SIZE;
        j = random() % SIZE;

        vtmp = v[i];

        v[i] = v[j];
        v[i] = vtmp;
    }
}

void
test(const char *testname,Error *err, double errorExpected)
{

    err->calcError(opt_mpi);

    double error;

    if (glob_rank == 0) {
        error = err->getError();
        cout << endl << "Test " << testname << " blad " << error << endl;

        if (fabs(error - errorExpected) > (0.001 + 0.001 * errorExpected)) {
            cerr << "Blad powinno byc " << errorExpected << endl;
            MPI_Finalize();
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            cout << " - - - - - - OK" << endl;
        }
    }
}

void
test1(Error *err)
{

    double x0[] = { -3, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 3 };
    double y0[] = { -3, -3, 3, -1, 1, -3, 3, 3 };
    double a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    double c[] = { 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05 };

    err->setCoefficients(x0, y0, a, c, 8);

    test("test1", err, 0);
}

void
test2(Error *err)
{

    double x0[] = { -3, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    double y0[] = { -3, -3, 3, -1, 1, -3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3 };
    double a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3 };
    double c[] = { 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };

    err->setCoefficients(x0, y0, a, c, 15);

    test("test2", err, 357.729);
}

void
test3(Error *err)
{

    double x0[] = { -3, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 3, -3, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -3, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    double y0[] = { -3, -3, 3, -1, 1, -3, 1, 3, -3, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -3, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    double *a = new double[38];
    double *c = new double[38];

    for (int i = 0; i < 38; i++) {
        a[i] = 1 + i / 38.0;
        c[i] = 2 + i / 38.0;
    }

    err->setCoefficients(x0, y0, a, c, 38);

    test("test3", err, 2975.86);
}

void
test4(Error *err)
{

    double *x0 = new double[150];
    double *y0 = new double[150];
    double *a = new double[150];
    double *c = new double[150];

    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        x0[i] = 5 - i * 0.2;
        a[i] = 1 + i / 8.0;
        y0[i] = 2 - i * 0.22;
        c[i] = 2 + i / 38.0;
    }

    err->setCoefficients(x0, y0, a, c, 150);

    test("test4", err, 3303.04);
}

void
testL(Error *err)
{
    double *x0;
    double *y0;
    double *a;
    double *c;

    if (glob_rank == 0)
        cout << "Test pozwalajacy na oszacowanie przyspieszenia" << endl;

    x0 = new double[111];
    y0 = new double[111];
    a = new double[111];
    c = new double[111];

    for (int i = 0; i < 111; i++) {
        x0[i] = 5 - i * 0.2;
        a[i] = 1 + i / 1.1;
        y0[i] = 2 - i * 0.4;
        c[i] = 2 + i / 38.0;
    }

    double toterror = 0;
    double error;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
        err->setCoefficients(x0, y0, a, c, 111 - i * 3);

        err->calcError(opt_mpi);

        error = err->getError();
        dbgprt(2,"testL: POST error=%g\n",error);

        if (glob_rank == 0) {
            toterror += error;
        }
    }

    if (glob_rank == 0)
        cout << "Uwaga: ta wartosc nie moze zalezec od liczby uzytych procesow = " << toterror << endl;
}

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char *cp;

    MPI_Init(&ac, &av);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &glob_rank);

#if 1
    ranseed = 123767832;
#else
    ranseed = 0;
#endif

    --ac;
    ++av;

    for (;  ac > 0;  --ac, ++av) {
        if (glob_rank != 0)
            break;

        cp = *av;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'd':
            opt_debug = 1;
            break;

        case 'M':
            opt_mpi = 1;
            break;

        case 'R':
            ranseed = atoi(cp + 2);
            break;

        case 'S':
            opt_send = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    tvzero = tvgetf();

    if (ranseed == 0)
        ranseed = time(NULL);
    if (glob_rank == 0) {
        cout << "Random: " << ranseed << std::endl;
        cout << "Mpi: " << opt_mpi << std::endl;
        cout << "Send: " << opt_send << std::endl;
        cout << "Debug: " << opt_debug << std::endl;
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&tvzero, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&ranseed, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&opt_mpi, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&opt_send, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&opt_debug, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    Error *err = new Error();
    double *v;

    v = new double[SIZE];
    double x0[] = { -3, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 3 };
    double y0[] = { -3, -3, 3, -1, 1, -3, 3, 3 };
    double a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    double c[] = { 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05 };

    generate(v, x0, y0, a, c);
    shuffle(v);

    // udostepniam dane dla procesu = 0
    err->setValues(v, LEN, MULT);

    test1(err);
    test2(err);
    test3(err);
    test4(err);
    test1(err);

    testL(err);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}

double
tvgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

int
dbgif(int lvl)
{
    int goflg = 0;

    do {
        if (! opt_debug)
            break;

        if (glob_rank == 0) {
            goflg = 1;
            break;
        }

        if (lvl > opt_debug)
            goflg = 1;
    } while (0);

    return goflg;
}

void
_dbgprt(const char *fmt,...)
{
    va_list ap;
    double tvnow;

    tvnow = tvgetf();
    tvnow -= tvzero;

    printf("%.9f/%d ",tvnow,glob_rank);

    va_start(ap,fmt);
    vprintf(fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I've updated my full code example above to add tracing. It seems to work in all cases.

However, to answer your followup questions ...

> what if I cannot modify the main class?

I presume you mean "main file" which includes the `test*` functions? **No.** You must modify the `test*` functions because they are the source of the bugs you're having.

> If I had to only modify Error, would it work if I moved out the MPI_reduce out of those loops, and added `error = error_p` at the end of the if statement as you suggested?

Mostly, but you want `error_p = error` instead. Reread my comment about this in my original post and reread the documentation for `MPI_Reduce`. First arg is what client sends to root and second arg is how root gets the value.

> Interesting enough I'm also not able to broadcast length_2.

That's because you were using `MPI_INT` instead of `MPI_DOUBLE`

> Then I guess I'd have to add all those Bcasts, but even if I broadcast the size value I dont know how to set the second parameter of the Bcast function for the rest of the arrays. Everything I try ends with segmentation fault.

You do *not* need to broadcast the `x0` et. al. arrays if you *always* set them in test*, *regardless* of rank. Remember that I mentioned that the calculation was small enough to be able to be repeated in all ranks

*Not* setting them in *all* ranks *is* the bug.

> As expected, no matter what I try, I'm not able to broadcast any array to the rest of the processes.

The broadcast part is working fine (i.e. rank 0 is sending the data correctly). But, the non-root ranks have no place to store it and you're getting segfaults.

Here is your `test4`:

```
void
test4(Error * err, int rank)
{

    if (rank == 0) {
        double *x0 = new double[150];
        double *y0 = new double[150];
        double *a = new double[150];
        double *c = new double[150];

        for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
            x0[i] = 5 - i * 0.2;
            a[i] = 1 + i / 8.0;
            y0[i] = 2 - i * 0.22;
            c[i] = 2 + i / 38.0;
        }

        err->setCoefficients(x0, y0, a, c, 150);
    }

    test(err, 3303.04, rank);
}
```

Here is the modified version:

```
void
test4(Error * err, int rank)
{
    double *x0 = new double[150];
    double *y0 = new double[150];
    double *a = new double[150];
    double *c = new double[150];

    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        x0[i] = 5 - i * 0.2;
        a[i] = 1 + i / 8.0;
        y0[i] = 2 - i * 0.22;
        c[i] = 2 + i / 38.0;
    }

    err->setCoefficients(x0, y0, a, c, 150);

    test(err, 3303.04, rank);
}
```

In my version, `setCoefficients` is *always* being called. So, the non-root rank `Error` class will *always* have valid [non-null] pointers for `x0`, etc.

In your version, `setCoefficients` is *only* called for the root rank. So, the non-root ranks will *always* have null pointers for `x0`, etc. Thus, you'll get a segfault.

Note that if you had compiled with `-Wall`, some of the `test*` functions would have been flagged with warnings about possibly uninitialized values. Fixing those would probably have put you on to the problem earlier.

At a minimum, even if you wish to bcast `x0` et. al., you must *still* ensure the child ranks have valid/sufficient space allocated.

To achieve this, here's a modified `test4`:

```
void
test4(Error * err, int rank)
{

    if (rank == 0) {
        double *x0 = new double[150];
        double *y0 = new double[150];
        double *a = new double[150];
        double *c = new double[150];

        for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
            x0[i] = 5 - i * 0.2;
            a[i] = 1 + i / 8.0;
            y0[i] = 2 - i * 0.22;
            c[i] = 2 + i / 38.0;
        }

        err->setCoefficients(x0, y0, a, c, 150);
    }
    else
        err->setBuffers(150);

    test(err, 3303.04, rank);
}
```

And, you'll need something like:

```
void
Error::setBuffers(int size)
{

    this->x0 = realloc(this->x0,sizeof(double) * size);
    this->y0 = realloc(this->y0,sizeof(double) * size);
    this->a = realloc(this->a,sizeof(double) * size);
    this->c = realloc(this->c,sizeof(double) * size);

    this->size = size;
}
```

So, after doing all that, you end up with a more complicated solution and you *still* have to modify `test*`.

Of course, in the MPI version of `calcError`, you'd want to do:

```
MPI_Bcast(x0, size, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I've a follow up question: what if I cannot modify the main class? If I had to only modify Error, would it work if I moved out the MPI_reduce out of those loops, and added error = error_p at the end of the if statement as you suggested? Then I guess I'd have to add all those Bcasts, but even if I broadcast the `size` value I dont know how to set the second parameter of the Bcast function for the rest of the arrays. Everything I try ends with segmentation fault.

Comment: As expected, no matter what I try, I'm not able to broadcast any array to the rest of the processes. Interesting enough I'm also not able to broadcast `length_2`. Is there a way to correct my version without modifying the main faile?